# AngularJS wait for all async calls to finish even if status 401 is returned?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I want to do the following, i have a controller like this:

```
  dashboardService.getDashboardStateLakes().then(function (result) {
            if (result) {
                dosomething();
        }, function (err) {
            //TODO: handle error;
            //alert(err);
            throw new Error(err);
        });

        // populate dashboard lakes status (left upper of the screen)
        dashboardService.getDashboardLakesStatus().then(function (result) {
            if (result) {
                dosomething();
            }
        }, function (err) {
            //alert(err);
            //throw new Error(err);
        });
```

and in the service it's doing like this:

```
 this.getDashboardLakesStatus = function () {
        var deffered = $q.defer();
        $http.get(api.GET_dashboardLakesStatus)
            .success(function (result) {
                //logic
                deffered.resolve(result);
            })
             .error(function (data, status) {
                //logic
                deffered.reject(status);
        return deffered.promise;
    };
```

Now all i want is to do something when both the ajax calls are finished, but the problem is, sometimes, a 401 is coming back (deliberately) and $q all stops when an error occurs...what is my other option?

Comment: I am unclear on what you want. Do you want to do some logic after the 2 $http.get finish regardless of whether they succeed? Or only if they succeed or what?

Comment: regardless if they succeed or not, that's right

Comment: Still not quite sure about the problem. Why dont you put your logic ( dosomething() ) to the error handlers as well?

Answer (score 3):

Promise exception handling is similar to try/catch in synchronous code. You can make the promise resolve by recovering it from bad state:

```
$http.get(api.GET_dashboardLakesStatus).catch(function(e){ });// always resolved
```

Take note that the result of this get call will either be the actual response or `undefined` if there was an error. This will let you `$q.all` several of these calls even if some of them fail.

Also, note you have the [deferred anti pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). You don't have to create a deferred when working with an API that already returns promises. Consider using `.then` and `.catch` in favor of `.success` and `.error` while you're at it.